# LVS support LTS 12.04

Tags: kernel

Does LTS 12.04 have LVS support built into Kernel ?
when I installed keepalived package I got this error:

```
Kernel does not support IPVS                                                                                                    
ipvsadm requires IPVS support in the kernel. Please use a kernel with IPVS modules, otherwise this software is pretty useless.
```

Anyone idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

get the kernel from the [download link](http://osdir.com/ml/linux.highavailability.ultramonkey/2006-02/msg00004.html) and compile and install it.